# Xamarin ios UItableView Empty rows at top using Task Scheduler in background

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin

I have one empty row in the top when I load `UITableView` object inside `UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginInvokeOnMainThread()` but it works fine (no empty row) without using `TaskFactory`.

Anyone has any idea? Thanks for your time and help.

```
var bounds = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
// show the loading overlay on the UI thread using the correct orientation sizing
loadingOverlay = new LoadingView(bounds, "Loading data...");
View.Add(loadingOverlay);
var context = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() ;
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    ApprovalPendingList = CommonWebServices.GetPurchaseOrders(AppDelegate.SysproID);
    ApprovalPendingListClone = new List<Approval>(ApprovalPendingList);


}).ContinueWith((result) =>
{
    try
    {
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>//UIApplication.SharedApplication.InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            tableViewApprovalList.Source = new TablePurchaseOrderPendingListSource(ApprovalPendingList);         
            Add(tableViewApprovalList);
            tableViewApprovalList.ReloadData(); 
            tableViewApprovalList.SizeToFit(); 
            UICommon.SetHeaderColor(this.NavigationController, this.NavigationItem, "Pending Orders");                             
        });
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        //  throw;
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not use async/await?

Comment: Thank you. But I tried.still it doesn't work